# validate parameter in ReadFromText does not work on GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

when running the flows locally and passing the non-existing local address as input (i.e. the url of a non-existing file), the validate parameter of ReadFromText works perfectly and raises an error. However, the flow does not throw any error when running on GCP (GCS address as input). By that, I mean the validate parameter has no effect, and the flow continues as if an existing file with empty text inside is passed. Is there a workaround for this?

apache beam pipeline in GCP dataflow

I expect an error to be raised and so the flow should fail. But the flow continues with an empty pcollection silently.

Comment: Are you using python SDK?

Comment: Yes Rui I’m using python 2.7

Comment: Does the GCS address contain any glob patterns, or end in a '/'?